# Too many open files SMB / NextCloud

Tags: samba, nextcloud

I am using an app called ‘Duplicate Finder’ in NextCloud to scan if i have duplicate images.
When i try to run the program, i get the following error in my apache2 error log:

```
[Thu Aug 06 14:45:08.221982 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10545:tid 140179276822272] 
[client 192.168.2.254:49802] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: {"reqId":"cI05UvQK2IMSj7vhgbsr","level":3,"time":"2020-08-06T12:45:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.254","user":"root","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/duplicatefinder/files","message":"proc_open(): unable to dup File-Handle for descriptor 3 - Too many open files at 
/var/www/nextcloud/apps/files_external/3rdparty/icewind/smb/src/Wrapped/RawConnection.php#76","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.1.1"}PHP message: {"reqId":"cI05UvQK2IMSj7vhgbsr","level":3,"time":"2020-086T12:45:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.254","user":"root","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/duplicatefinder/files","message":"include(/var/www/nextcloud/apps/files_external/3rdparty/icewind/smb/src/Exception/ConnectionException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files at 
/var/www/nextcloud/lib/composer/composer/ClassLoader.php#444","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.1.1"}PHP message: {"reqId":"cI05UvQK2IMSj7vhgbsr","level":3,"time":"2020-08-06T12:45:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.254","user":"root","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/duplicatefinder/files","message":"include(): Failed opening '/var/www/nextcloud/apps/files_external/3rdparty/composer/../icewind/smb/src/Exception/ConnectionException.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Crypt_Blowfish:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Date:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Exception:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Idna:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Imap_Client:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_ListHeaders:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Mail:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Mime:/var/www/nextcloud/apps/mail/vendor/pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_N...PHP message: {"reqId":"cI05UvQK2IMSj7vhgbsr","level":3,"time":"2020-08-
06T12:45:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.254","user":"root","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/duplicatefinder/files","message":"Trying to access array offset on value of type null at 
/var/www/nextcloud/apps/files_external/3rdparty/icewind/smb/src/Wrapped/RawConnection.php#139","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.1.1"}PHP message: {"reqId":"cI05UvQK2IMSj7vhgbsr","level":3,"time":"2020-08-06T12:45:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.254","user":"root","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/duplicatefinder/files","message":"get_resource_type() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given at 
/var/www/nextcloud/apps/files_external/3rdparty/icewind/smb/src/Wrapped/Connection.php#120","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.1.1"}'
```

Could some one help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an workaround and used SFTP for external storage on NextCloud in stead of SMB. Now it works!